# Convert flat indexed array to 2d associative array then merge with another 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays :

```
Array 1
(
    [0] => 976504282322
    [1] => 976530000022
)
```

=====

```
Array 2
(
    [0]  => Array
        (
            [Mobile]  => 978504282398
            [Name]  => Mike 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Mobile]  => 976504282300
            [Name]  => Jhon
        )
)
```

====

I want to merge them and the final result should be :

===

```
Array3
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Mobile]  => 978504282398
            [Name]  => Mike 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Mobile]  => 976504282300
            [Name]  => Jhon
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Mobile]  => 976504282322

        )

   [3] => Array
        (
            [Mobile]  => 976504282322

        )


)
```

Note : performance is very important here because each array have over 200,000 item , so using for loop is not a good idea.

my code :

```
foreach ($Array1 as $mobile=> $value) {
    $Array2[]['Mobile']=$value;
}
```

Comment: If `performance is very important part here` then where is your tried code?

Comment: I solve this using for loop but it take long time to move item from array1 & array2 to array3

Comment: @Ali Show us your loop and we may provide improvements, as the current status of your question, it seems more like `GIVE ME ZE CODEZ`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV what did you mean by "GIVE ME ZE CODEZ" ???

Comment: "so using for loop is not a good idea." --- why do you think so? Even if you don't see an explicit `for` loop, it doesn't mean there is no one performed implicitly (assuming there is a magic function especially for your case)

Comment: @Ali It means `Give me the code`, to make it simple: guys who doesn't show efforts on solving *their* problems don't get usually help from us.

Comment: @zerkms  my question is there any php function like array_merge that do what i need ?

Comment: @Ali: there is no a **single** function for this particular case.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV it is simple so no need to write the code ,,, any why i have updated the question

Comment: @Ali just saying, usually this will get downvoted/closed. Anyways if you don't wanna use a for/foreach loop, use `array_map()`...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV thanks, please check the question again , i have added the code

Comment: @Ali I think that is one of the fastest way to achieve the desired results, how long does it take ?

Comment: The provided code would generate a notice, use `$Array2[] = array('Mobile' => $value);` instead

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV  it takes over 15 sec if i have more than 100,000

Comment: Is it important to check if the number in the first array already exists as a mobile number in the second array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a oneliner:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);

$b = array(array('Mobile' => 1, 'name' => 'Mike'));

var_dump(
    array_merge($b, array_map(function($i) { return array('Mobile' => $i); }, $a))
);
```

PS: even though you don't see a loop explicitly - php performs it internally.

PPS: personally I would create a performance test to compare a straightforward `for` base solution. And I'm sure it will be better (and will consume less memory without doubts)

Comment: Note(!!), this code will work only on PHP >= 5.3.0, as 5.3 introduced anonymous functions. Nice solution.

Comment: @Valentin Rusk: it can easily be rewritten to a separate function ;-) If OP has pre-5.3 version then it's a homework

Answer (score 2):

Why not [Array_Merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ? Especially for such tasks, merging multiple arrays.
But you will need to store

```
Array 1
(
    [0] => 976504282322
    [1] => 976530000022
)
```

as

```
Array 1
(
    [0] => array('Mobile'=>976504282322)
    [1] => array('Mobile'=>976530000022)
)
```

and then you are ready to merge.
anywawys should be faster than looping 200k array.
In case you don't care for array indexing, you could also try

```
$arr = $arr + $arr2; // appending
```

Comment: This will be great idea if OP convert his 1D array to 2D array, but this also require `for` loop, but OP doesn't want to use it.

Comment: great but how can I store the array1 as what you meantioned above ,,

Comment: assume my numbers stored like this $numbers="976504282322,976530000022"

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function my_array_merge() {
    $new = array();
    foreach (func_get_args() as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
            if (!is_array($item)) {
                $item = array('Mobile' => $item);
            }
            $new[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Example:

```
$arr1 = array(
    '976504282322',
    '976530000022',
);
$arr2 = array(
    array(
        'Mobile' => '978504282398',
        'Name'   => 'Mike',
    ),
    array(
        'Mobile' => '976504282300',
        'Name'   => 'John',
    ),
);
print_r(my_array_merge($arr2,$arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked good

```
<?php
$array = array("a" , "b", "c" ,"d");
$array1 = array(1 , 2, 3 ,4);
$sum=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
$sum[$i][1]=$array[$i];
$sum[$i][2]=$array1[$i];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sum);
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.